# How to rewrite ULCO error compare between genvar and int?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Trying to propagate a valid signal to one of several destinations I write the following code. The problem is there is a ULCO error (Unequal length in comparison operator) between the genvar `unit` and the register `current_unit_r`. What is the recommended way to describe this logic?

```
input wire valid;
wire [NUM_UNITS-1:0] valid_per_unit;

genvar unit;
generate
   for (unit = 0; unit < NUM_UNITS; unit++) begin : gen_valid_per_unit
      assign valid_per_unit[unit] = valid && (unit == current_unit_r);
   end
endgenerate
```

Comment: You could change the comparison to `(unit[0+:DESIRED_WIDTH] == current_unit_r[0+:DESIRED_WIDTH])`.

Comment: @TomCarpenter That's what I did.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a cast to eliminate size mismatch errors

```
input wire valid;
wire [NUM_UNITS-1:0] valid_per_unit;

for (genvar unit = 0; unit < NUM_UNITS; unit++) begin : gen_valid_per_unit
      assign valid_per_unit[unit] = valid && (unit == int'(current_unit_r));
end
```